Failed to prepare executable target with name "undefined"
When I run flutter project with Ctrl+F5 then the output is:
[main] Configuring project: qlnha_app 
[proc] Executing command: "E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -SE:/Users/thaichau/Projects/VietGis/qlnha_app/qlnha_app/linux/flutter -Be:/Users/thaichau/Projects/VietGis/qlnha_app/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Error: The source "E:/Users/thaichau/Projects/VietGis/qlnha_app/qlnha_app/linux/flutter/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "E:/Users/thaichau/Projects/VietGis/qlnha_app/qlnha_app/build/windows/x64/_deps/nuget-subbuild/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
[proc] The command: "E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -SE:/Users/thaichau/Projects/VietGis/qlnha_app/qlnha_app/linux/flutter -Be:/Users/thaichau/Projects/VietGis/qlnha_app/build -G "MinGW Makefiles" exited with code: 1
[main] Failed to prepare executable target with name "undefined"

I don't understand about system and CMake, that I expect anyone can help me to fix the problem. Can you instruct me to uninstall and reinstall that to easy?

Looks like you have copied the build directory (e:/Users/thaichau/Projects/VietGis/qlnha_app/build) from some other place, which has been used for configure other CMake project. Remove that directory and try again.
